# Acumular en columna - could not be converted to int

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente código en un controlador:

```
$total = DB::table('pedidos')->where('idUSUARIOS', $usuario)
                              ->orWhere('ESTADO','P')
                              ->pluck('TOTAL');

$precio=$request->get('precio');

DB::table('pedidos')
        ->where('idPEDIDOS',$idpedido)
        ->update(['TOTAL' => $total+$precio]);
```

Lo que trata de hacer es lo que hay en la columna TOTAL ir acumulando el precio de otro producto, pero me da error en la siguiente linea:

```
->update(['TOTAL' => $total+$precio]);
```

El error que da es:

```
Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int
```

¿Alguien sabe el motivo de este error?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: No mandes el update como array asociativo

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo he solucionado tal y como indica Alfredo, pero además he tenido que añadir el siguiente código antes del update:

```
$precio=floatval(str_replace(",","",$precio));
$total=floatval(str_replace(",","",$total));
$total=$total+$precio;
```

Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema. Los campos los he transformado de decimales a float.